# How to deduce iterator template type, or its template's nested type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

This questions begs a more preparation, so I provide some bits of code first and then the exact question

Assuming I have the following type declared

```
template<typename T>
struct some_type
{
    T t_;
};
```

which would be constructed with a factory function like so

```
typedef float numeric_type;
std::vector<std::string> construction_material;
//Push_back of strings in certain form...
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<some_type<numeric_type>> instances;
build_instances(construction_material.begin(), construction_material.end(), back_inserter(instances));
```

and the construction function would be *something like* following

```
template<typename input_iterator, typename output_iterator>
output_iterator build_instances(input_iterator begin, input_iterator end, output_iterator out)
{
    for(input_iterator iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        //This won't work, but to illustrate some ideas...
        //build_instance<std::iterator_traits<output_iterator>::value_type>(*iter)
    }

    //[...]

    return *out;
}

template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<some_type<T>> build_instance(std::string const& material)
{
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<T>::value == true, "The template type needs to be a floating point type.");

    std::unique_ptr<some_instance<T>> instance(new some_instance<T>());
    //Some processing...

    return instance;
}
```

I know I could change the function to return some container (or perhaps even templatize the container type), like

```
template<typename input_iterator, typename T>
std::vector<std::unique_type<T>> build_instances(input_iterator begin, input_iterator end,       
output_iterator out)
{
    //Likewise code to the previous snippets...
    return ...
}
```

The problems I haven't been able to solve are:

1. Would it be possible -- or impossible -- to use the *back_inserter* like approach? It looks like being the most flexible for the caller?
2. How to get a hold on the *numeric_type* in *build_instances* body (as in having it through output_iterator) so that it can be used in building the instances one-by-one?
3. How to ensure the caller knows to wait for the objects wrapped in std::unique_ptrs? An alternative would be just as plain pointers, but I'm not enthuasiastic about that.

There's a similar kind of question with a heading [How can I make this template method more elegant? (or: less explicit template parameters required)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350795/how-can-i-make-this-template-method-more-elegant-or-less-explicit-template-pa), which takes a container and transforms it to a different type of a container.

**Edit**
As commented to Jogojapan's comment that currently I transform the input like so

```
std::transform(construction_material.begin(), construction_material.end(), std::inserter(instances, instances.begin()), build_instance<numeric_type>);
```

<strike>but the subsequent function calls need to be supplied the `numeric_type` typedef too, which is somewhat cumbersome. I hope to avoid that.</strike> It looks I was mistaken, but for the purpose of education and all, would it be possible to further reduce the need to typedef the numeric type and deduce it from the iterator?

Comment: For question 2., maybe something like decltype(*((*it).front().get())) would work?

Comment: What's the role/significance of `some_type<T>`? In your example, the caller prepares a `vector<unique_ptr<float>>`, but `build_instances()` seems to fill a `vector<unique_ptr<some_type<float>>>`, or did I misunderstand anything. Also, in `build_instance()` you seem to switch the name of the type from `some_type<T>` to `some_instance<T>`.

Comment: @Moritz, I'll get back to that after a while.

Comment: Jogojapan, Good catch! I'll edit the text! The role of some_type is to be a bunch of different kinds of tokens, of which the type parameter has importace. Currently the construction goes like "std::transform(construction_material.begin(), construction_material.end(), std::inserter(instances, instances.begin()), build_instance<numeric_type>);" the problem I see is that the template type needs to be repeated in subsequent function calls as it's needed too.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your solution to (2) works - very similar code compiles for me using GCC 4.6 and `-std=c++0x`.  Why do you think it won't work?

Comment: Tom, it looks I've made a blunder in how I thought about this, if I have functions like template<typename T>
void function1(std::unique_ptr<some_type<T>> const& instance) calling the constructed some_type<T> instances will work without supplying the T type explicitly as in function<numeric_type>. Now all that I have left is to wonder if I can remove the need to explicitly define a type first for the container and then to the transform/factory function. Granted, I can make a local typedef (as in the code), but it'd be cool if I could somehow avoid that too -- and learn something in the process.

Comment: Moritz, compiler (VS 2012 RC) gives an error message "2039: 'front' : is not a member of 'std::back_insert_iterator<_Container>'". So, I guess this should be something more general, which I was hoping to achieve with the traits stuff. Good point, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An intrusive solution is to let `some_type` exposes its type parameter, the same way `std::unique_ptr<T, D>` exposes its first parameter via `element_type` (which we will need later):

```
template<typename T>
struct some_type
{
    // give it an appropriate meaningful name
    using value_type = T;
    value_type t_;
};

template<typename input_iterator, typename output_iterator>
output_iterator build_instances(input_iterator begin, input_iterator end, output_iterator out)
{
    using pointer_type = typename std::iterator_traits<output_iterator>::value_type;
    using value_type = typename pointer_type::element_type::value_type;
    return std::transform(begin, end, out, build_instance<value_type>);
}
```

You can also non-intrusively extract the first template parameter of a template specialization:

```
template<typename T>
struct first;

template<template<typename...> class Template, typename First, typename... Pack>
struct first<Template<First, Pack...>>> {
    using type = First;
};

template<typename T>
using First = typename first<T>::type;
```

The `value_type` alias in `build_instances` would instead become

```
using value_type = First<typename pointer_type::element_type>;
```

As a final remark I find it a bit odd that `build_instance` take a `T` parameter but constructs instances of `some_type<T>`. If it took `T` and constructed instances of `T` (where perhaps `T` is restricted to be a specialization of `some_type`.) This would have spared your problem, too.

Comment: I just woke up and I have to let this to sink in to me for a few moments. :-) I'm somewhat green with templates, so that factors in as to why I've used the T parameter as I've had. Albeit I don't immediately see how changing the parameter from plain T to some_type<T> would make the problems go away. I guess what I'm trying to do is to user inserter that fills some arbitrary container with the constructed instances, taken as  parameter, instead of returning a "pre-selected container", say, std::vector<some_type<numeric_type>>. This got a bit out of hand, but then again, learning is good!

Comment: @Veksi I just realised my answer was incomplete.

Comment: I need to test this on g++, but it looks plausible. VC 2012 RC doesn't support variadic templates...

Comment: @Veksi You can special-case `first` (and `First`) to extract the one parameter of a one parameter template specialization, to suit your needs. The version I show is general just for the sake of it.